# list and string and loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function that asks the user to select letters to a mystery word. More than 4 wrong guesses by the user results in the computer saying ‘Game Over.’ More than 4 correct guesses results in the computer saying “Okay, now try to guess the word.’ If the guess is correct, than it says “You win.”

Comment: C`mon, at least reword the homework question and have an attempt at it!

Comment: I would but honestly i have no idea how to start. I don't need the entire. just need an idea on how to do it. and i will figure it out from there

Comment: import random
#create wordlist here
#create empty list called progres here
#answer = random.choice from wordlist
#for troubleshooting purposes, print answer
#wrong = 0
#correct=0

Comment: #while wrong < 4 and correct < 4:
    #guess = input('Guess a letter.')
    #if guess not in answer:
        #print ('Nope.')
        #wrong +=1
    #if guess in answer:
        #print (guess)
        #progress.append(guess)
        #correct +=1
        #print ('Progress so far: ', progress, '.')
#now, create an if-then statement which says if you 
#have 4 correct answers, to take a guess. if the guess
#matches the 'answer' then it says 'you guessed right.'
#if wrong ==4:
    #print('Game Over.')

Comment: @user1742146: Edit your answer with the code, rather than putting it in a comment. You can format it properly that way, so we can understand it.

Comment: Ad your code to your question.  Put 4 spaces in front of each line of code and it will display properly

Answer (score 2):

You may be capable to some of the steps below, no offence. Do more of small steps. Learn how to divide the bigger problem to smaller ones. Imagine how would you do it without a coputer -- just with your friend, using a paper and pencil:

- Write a single `print(...)` command to say *Hello*, and store it into a `guess.py` file.
- Learn how to launch a Python program.
- Write a function `game` around the above `print` (i.e. one more line before, plus indentation of the `print`.
- Add calling the function below the function definition.
- Launch the `guess.py` again (i.e. the same output, different implementation).
- Add reading an input from the keyboard (the `input('prompt:')`, store it to the `x` variable, and print the variable.
- Launch the program.
- Add the variable `playing` to the beginning of the function and initialize it to `True`.
- Add the `while playing:` loop just below and indent the `input` and `print` commands to have them in the loop.
- Launch the program, quit it using Ctrl+C.
- Change the `print(x)` to `print(repr(x))` to see what you really get from the `input`.
- Launch.
- Add the `x = x.rstrip()` just below the `input` line and above the `print`.
- Launch.
- Add the folowing test to the end of the while-loop body.

.

```
if x == '': 
    playing = False
```

- Launch and just press Enter without any character if you want to quit the program.

(to be continued after first trials)

Think about how would you generate a magical word (using paper, pencil and some random method to choose characters). Think about how to store the word. How would you check if the character is inside? How would you check the number of guess attempts? Enhance the program using the small steps so that it always work. Stop programming when it does what you expect.